# Asp.net radio button, how to change the rendered label server side?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having to modify some existing code for a radio button that has a bunch of logic based around the value and Id for a radio button.  All I really need to do is change the label and I don't really want to modify the generated input tag since it breaks the messy logic.  Does anyone know how to do this server side?  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing it client side.

```
                $(function() {
                        var capRateLabel = $('lblCapRate').next();
                        if(capRateLabel)
                        {
                            capRateLabel.text('newtext'); 
                        }
                })
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether i've understood your question or not. But a [`RadioButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.aspx) has a [`Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158234.aspx) property.

```
RadioButton1.Text = "anytext";
```

**Edit**: If you instead want to change the label of the RadioButton control, you can use the [`LabelAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3se8ewc%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property([inherited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.labelattributes.aspx) from CheckBox).

For example:

```
RadioButton1.LabelAttributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor = 'red'");
```

or

```
RadioButton1.LabelAttributes.CssStyle.Add("text-decoration", "line-through");
```

Comment: I'm going to slap myself if that's the answer... seriously.

Answer (score 2):

Simply through the Text property:

```
MyRadioButton.Text = "My Radio Button";
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to change about the label. You can use the `LabelAtttributes` to add or remove attributes, the `Text` property to change the text, etc., but that's about it.

If you need more than that I would consider building your own `RadioButton` control; it really wouldn't be that difficult, and it would give you whatever flexibility you need.